# Rails: Font awesome icons not showing using font-awesome-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, font-awesome

I can't seem to find an answer that works for me.

The icon shows up as a box: 

I'm using:

```
font-awesome-rails (4.6.2.0)
rails (4.2.3)
```

I imported font-awesome-rails in my application.scss file using:

```
@import "font-awesome";
```

and here is what I wrote for the view:

```
<i class="quote-left fa fa-quote-left"></i>
```

I've tried including it before and after bootstrap.

I also tried manually adding the font folder to the pipeline in application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

Clearing the tmp folder didn't seem to do anything either.

I spent way too much time on this, please help :(

Comment: Do the font-awesome-rails helper methods work? Just to make sure that you're not making a mistake with your `<i>` elements. E.g. if you replace your `<i>[...]</i>` with `<%= fa_icon('quote-left') %>` (assuming you are using ERB)?

Comment: I'm currently using redcarpet markdown generation to include the html directly into my article. The html was copied from chrome inspection.

Comment: Do you see a font-file loading error inside browser console? and are you sure your font-awesome font files are inside the assets/fonts folder?

Comment: no font file loading errors in console. I'm not sure if it is located inside the font folder. The gem should be adding them automatically. Whtat's the best way to check?

Comment: check your app/assets/fonts folder. if not there you can move the font files there or the second option is remove the font-awesome-rails gem and place this inside the head tag 

<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
 Try with this approach, it should work.

Comment: Yeah, I may have to just do this manually. Thanks for all your help. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: <%= fa_icon('quote-left') %> worked for me! instead of <i> </i> elements. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue when working with **Rails 6** and **Bootstrap 4** in **Ubuntu 20.04**.

**I had set up Fontawesome this way**:

First I added Font Awesome to my `package.json` file:

```
yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

Next, I imported it into my `app/javascript/packs/application.js` file:

```
require("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free")
```

Next, I imported it into my `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` file:

```
$fa-font-path: '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/v4-shims';
```

I also added the [Font Awesome 5 Rails](https://github.com/tomkra/font_awesome5_rails) gem to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'font_awesome5_rails'
```

and installed it in my project:

```
bundle install
```

And finally I modified where my fontawesome icons were called from this format:

```
<i class="fas fa-camera-retro"></i>
```

to this format

```
fa_icon('camera-retro')
```

But the issue was that the icons were displaying fine in development but not in production.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The issue was that I needed to import the **FontAwesome 5** fonts into the `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` file. So I imported this to it:

```
@import 'font_awesome5_webfont';
```

So my fontawesome import to the `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` file looked like this finally:

```
@import 'font_awesome5_webfont';
$fa-font-path: '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/v4-shims';
```

This time the icons displayed properly in development as well as production.

**Note**: Please ensure to re-compile your assets after making these changes and restart your server.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: perfect answer so far

Answer (score 2):

I moved my import of font-awesome below my font import and it solved it.

**from this:**

```
@import "font-awesome"; 
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:700,900");
```

**to this:**

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:700,900");
@import "font-awesome";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your webserver, after adding **@import 'font-awesome.css'** to your **application.scss**.

Also read these, if you haven't yet,

https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails/issues/130#issuecomment-95308175

https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed

Comment: I have tried restarting my server and even tried switching from the default rails server to puma with no luck. Does import 'font-awesome.css' differ from import 'font-awesome'? Either way, the css files seem to be getting concatenated into application.scss with no problems. Also, I am using the 'font-awesome' gem and not the 'font-awesome-rails' gem as the latter doesn't seem like it is being updated.

Comment: The 'font-awesome-rails' get updated regularly and I think you should use that. Also, I don't think 'font-awesome.css' and 'font-awesome' is any different, but its better to give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give the rails gem a try.

Comment: Ah, looks like I was confused. I AM using the font-awesome-rails gem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by explicitly declaring a `font-family: FontAwesome;` rule in my stylesheet because a global `*` style was overwriting the `font-family` attribute for the `.fa` class.